# Drag and drop in scrollable container on element with dynamic height broken in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, drag-and-drop, draggable

I have a scrollable container with a fixed height, in this container I have some `ul` lists with `li` items.

In my solution JavaScript is used to give all `ul` elements the same height, based on the element with the biggest height.
I prepared a simple [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pa1k5rmd/9/), but it perfectly shows the issue.

Now it seems a drop in Internet Explorer is only possible in the area of the target list, which has been visible without scrolling.
It works without problems in Firefox and Chrome.

**Steps to reproduce**:

1. Open fiddle in Internet Explorer (10/11)
2. Drag an item from the left side to the right side.
3. You see a *copy/move possible icon*
4. Scroll the container to the bottom
5. Drag an item from the left side to the right side.
6. You see a *forbbidden icon* below a specific invisible point

Has anybody ever faced this issue?
Is this really a bug of Internet Explorer or did I made some mistakes?
Is this also broken in Edge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove the `height` from the `inner` class. This occurs because the height of the inner container is set `100%` which equals the scrollable container height.